# How to navigate from a screen to another in Jetpack Compose using navController?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-architecture-navigation

I have this structure:

```
val navController = rememberNavController()
NavHost(
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = "auth"
) {
    composable(
        route = "auth"
    ) {
        AuthScreen(
            navController = navController
        )
    }
    composable(
        route = "profile"
    ) {
        ProfileScreen(
            navController = navController
        )
    }
}
```

When I first time open the app, I display a screen according to the authentication state:

```
if (!viewModel.isUserAuthenticated) {
    AuthScreen(navController = navController)
} else {
    ProfileScreen(navController = navController)
}
```

Which works fine. The problem comes, when I try to sing-in in the AuthScreen:

```
when(val response = authViewModel.signInState.value) {
    is Response.Loading -> CircularProgressIndicator()
    is Response.Success -> {
        if (response.data) {
            navController.navigate("profile")
            Log.d(TAG, "Success")
        }
    }
    is Response.Error -> Log.d(TAG, response.message)
}
```

The log statement prints "Success" but it doesn't navigate to the next ProfileScreen. How to solve this?

Comment: Where have you put the middle if-else condition? You are displaying composables yourself here instead of navigating to them and letting NavController display them.

Comment: @ArpitShukla I put the if statement in `setContent`, right after the first code. Yes, this is what I'm doing, I'm just displaying those screens according to the state. If I try to navigate change `AuthScreen(navController = navController)` with `navController.navigate("auth")`, I get NPE pointing to the `navController.navigate("auth")`, where is said that navController is null.

Comment: Ahh classic. This is the biggest issue of jetpack navigation, completely ignored by a Google. There's no way of changing the "root" screen, so your graph have to have a single point of entry. You'll be better off using simple stack or voyager for that matter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove that if-else from the `setContent`. Instead, make `ProfileScreen` as the home destination and inside it you can check whether user is authenticated or not. If he is not, navigate to the `AuthScreen`

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ProfileScreen(navController: NavController) {
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        if(!viewModel.isUserAuthenticated) {
            navController.navigate("auth")
        }
    }
}
```

If user can logout from this screen (i.e. auth state can change), then instead of `Unit` use `viewModel.isUserAuthenticated` as the key for `LaunchedEffect` (assuming that `isUserAuthenticated` is a `State`)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, it's a state. Let me try it.

Comment: It works, but there is an issue. If the user is not authenticated, when I launch the app, it displays the ProfileScreen, and right after that ithe AuthScreen. How to display the AuthScreen first without seeing the ProfileScreen? I upvoted your answer.

Comment: When do you set the value of this boolean? After the `ProfileScreen` is launched?

Comment: In the ViewModel I use `val isUserAuthenticated get() = useCase.isUserAuthenticated()`. Which by default is false, since the user is not authenticated.

Comment: One way could be to wrap everything inside `ProfileScreen` (other than `LaunchedEffect`) in `if(viewModel.isAuthenticated) { ... }`

Comment: So you say to add everything else inside the if statement? But I don't have anything related to the UI. I thin the issue is in the  setContent, where I have the code in the first code. Could it be because of that?

Comment: You still have the if-else inside `setContent`? You can remove that.

Comment: No, I don't. That was the first thing I done. I remove that.

Comment: You are seeing the ProfileScreen first as that is the start destination. We navigate to the auth screen only when `ProfileScreen` is loaded, that's why you see a glimpse of `ProfileScreen` on opening the app.

Comment: Btw what did you mean by `But I don't have anything related to the UI.` Don't you have any UI inside `ProfileScreen()` function?

Comment: Ok, I understand why I see the ProfileScreen first, but is there any solution to not see that screen first? As it is confusing the users? Besides that, in the ProfileScreen I only have the log out option in the menu. That's it. Thanks in advance for your patience.

Comment: Did you try putting the entire screen content inside `if(viewModel.isAuthenticated) { ... }` as I suggested above?

Comment: Let me try and get back to you.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Can you please help me with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70245355/how-to-create-a-viewmodel-object-inside-composable-function-correctly)? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

***Here is a much more detailed answer with code and demo if someone is looking***

---

**Code**:

**ComposeNavigationActivity.kt**

```
class ComposeNavigationActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {Navigation()}
    }
}
```

**Composables**

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen(navController: NavController) {
    var inputFieldText by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Red),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        TextField(
            value = inputFieldText,
            onValueChange = {
                inputFieldText = it
            },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(30.dp)
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        Button(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(5.dp),
            onClick = {
                navController.navigate(Screen.DetailScreen.withArgs(inputFieldText))
            }) {
            Text(
                text = "Navigate",
                color = Color.White,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                fontSize = 20.sp
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun DetailScreen(name: String?) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Green),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        name?.let {
            Text(
                text = it,
                color = Color.White,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                fontSize = 30.sp
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**A Sealed class to track routes**

```
sealed class Screen(val route:String){
    object MainScreen : Screen(route = "main_screen")
    object DetailScreen : Screen(route = "detail_screen")


    fun withArgs(vararg args:String) : String {
        return buildString {
            append(route)
            args.forEach { arg ->
                append("/$arg")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Navigation**

```
@Composable
fun Navigation() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Screen.MainScreen.route) {
        composable(route = Screen.MainScreen.route) {
            MainScreen(navController = navController)
        }
        composable(
            route = Screen.DetailScreen.route + "/{name}",
            arguments = listOf(
                navArgument("name") {
                    type = NavType.StringType
                    defaultValue = "Some Default"
                    nullable = true
                }
            )
        ) { entry ->
            DetailScreen(name = entry.arguments?.getString("name"))
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]