# @Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function in android

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, androidx

I'm new to the `Jetpack Compose`, and I'm trying to implement a function inside a button but it gives the following error:

> @Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a
> @Composable function in mContext.startActivity(Intent(mContext,
> MainScreen()::class.java))

```kotlin
        @Composable
         fun AdminAuth() {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(20.dp),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            var password by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
            var passawordVisibility by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
            
            val icon = if (passawordVisibility)
                painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_visibility)
            else
                painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_visibility_off)
            Text(text = "Insira a senha do usuário Master:", fontSize = 15.sp)
            OutlinedTextField(
                value = password, 
                onValueChange = {
                    password = it
                },
                placeholder = { Text(text = "Senha") },
                label = { Text(text = "Senha") },
                trailingIcon = {
                    IconButton(onClick = {
                        passawordVisibility = !passawordVisibility
                    }) {
                        Icon(
                            painter = icon,
                            contentDescription = "Ícone de visibilidade"
                        )
                    }
                },
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                    keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password
                ),
                visualTransformation = if (passawordVisibility)
                VisualTransformation.None
                else PasswordVisualTransformation()
            )
    
            val mContext = LocalContext.current
            OutlinedButton(
                onClick = {
                    if (password.equals("Abac@xi123")) {
                        mContext.startActivity(Intent(mContext, MainScreen()::class.java))
                    }
                },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(35.dp),
            ) {
                Text(text = "Entrar")
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    @Composable
    @Preview
    fun AdminAuthPreview() {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color.White),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            AdminAuth()
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the MainScreen? Another Composable or an Activity?

Answer (score 2):

```
mContext.startActivity(Intent(mContext, MainScreen()::class.java))
```

This is not correct way to change Compose. Not even for changing Activity either even if MainScreen is an Activity because of ***MainScreen()*** it should be `MainScreen`

Composable functions are like suspending functions that require you to call them as a lambda, function parameter, insider param or as getter.

[What are differents between Composable function and normal function in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73220189/what-are-differents-between-composable-function-and-normal-function-in-android/73261429#73261429)

```
@Target(
    // function declarations
    // @Composable fun Foo() { ... }
    // lambda expressions
    // val foo = @Composable { ... }
    AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION,

    // type declarations
    // var foo: @Composable () -> Unit = { ... }
    // parameter types
    // foo: @Composable () -> Unit
    AnnotationTarget.TYPE,

    // composable types inside of type signatures
    // foo: (@Composable () -> Unit) -> Unit
    AnnotationTarget.TYPE_PARAMETER,

    // composable property getters and setters
    // val foo: Int @Composable get() { ... }
    // var bar: Int
    //   @Composable get() { ... }
    AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER
)
annotation class Composable
```

If you wish to change UI using Compose you can use

conditional Composition or Compose navigation to navigate to next UI or screen.

Conditional change is generally by a State or a flag

```
var screenState by remember{mutableStateOf(Idle)}

   OutlinedButton(
        onClick = {
            if (password.equals("Abac@xi123")) {
                screenState = Success
            }
        },
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(35.dp),
    ) {
        Text(text = "Entrar")
    }

when(screenState) {
  Idle -> // Show Composable for this state
  Success -> // Show Composable when user enters valid password
  else -> // Implement other states of UI
}
```

or using navigation using a callback instead of passing navigationController

and in root navigating using this callback

```
   OutlinedButton(
        onClick = {
            if (password.equals("Abac@xi123")) {
                   navigateToSuccessScreen()
                }
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(35.dp),
        ) {
            Text(text = "Entrar")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong calling `startActivity` inside `onClick`, but you should **NOT** call the `MainScreen's` constructor (assuming it's an `Activity`), you can simply remove the parenthesis and it will be fine.

```
onClick = {
   if (password.equals("Abac@xi123")) {
            mContext.startActivity(Intent(mContext, MainScreen::class.java))
   }
}
```

But I suspect `MainScreen` is just another `@Composable` screen and not an `Activity` that you want to navigate to and your'e having that error because

> you cannot call a composable inside non-composable functions

like the compile error you are seeing.

I would suggest further reading and especially watching the live coding, you will see first hand how to navigate from a composable screen to another.

[Official Docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation)

[Some Related Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70142043/how-to-navigate-from-a-screen-to-another-in-jetpack-compose-using-navcontroller)

[Philipp Lackner's Note App](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8YPXv7xKh2w)